# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an application that allows someone to search for an exact result via the ID or if you don't know the ID you can search for part of their name to return accounts that match.

E.g Bob Jones is ID A01, you can either search for A01 to return Bob Jones or search B to return Bob Jones, Bradley Smith e.t.c...

I have coded the ID part just fine for some reason the second part doesn't work when it's practically the same code.

```
private void btnSaveEmployees_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        //First search for the entered text to see if it is an ID
        DataBase db = new DataBase(); //Construct a new database.
        db.OpenConnection(); //Open our Database connection

        MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `employee_ID` = @employeeID LIMIT 1", db.connection);
        mysqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", txtEmployeeID.Text);

        MySqlDataReader reader = mysqlCmd.ExecuteReader(); //Construct a reader 

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //Employee ID has been found so lets update the update form.
            Form employee = new UpdateEmployee(reader["firstName"].ToString(), reader["lastName"].ToString(), reader["contactNumber"].ToString(), reader["employee_access_level"].ToString());
            employee.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            db.CloseConnection();
            db.OpenConnection();
            MySqlDataReader Reader2;
            MySqlCommand mysqlCmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT firstName, LastName FROM `employees` WHERE `firstName` LIKE '"+txtEmployeeID.Text+"';", db.connection);
            //mysqlCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textbox", txtEmployeeID.Text);
            Reader2 = mysqlCmd2.ExecuteReader(); //Construct a reader

            while (Reader2.Read()==false)
            {
                listboxFindEmployees.Visible = true;
                string thisrow = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < Reader2.FieldCount; i++)
                    thisrow += Reader2.GetValue(i).ToString() + ",";

                listboxFindEmployees.Items.Add(thisrow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put some effort in making your code sample read well, and at least look as though it compiles.

Comment: "doesn't work" - define "doesn't work" please; what happens?

Comment: btw; your query is open to SQL injection attacks. You should use a parameter rather than concatenating `txtEmployeeID.Text` into the SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first sight you need to change

```
while (Reader2.Read()==false)
```

by

```
while (Reader2.Read())
```

You while condition is only allowing to enter when there is no more records to read so it will fail to execute the logic inside.

Your logic has some extra problems you should address

- You're exposed to sql injection attacks building queries using string concatenations. Use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx) instead.
- You have to release every instance that implement `IDisposable` interface (MySqlConnection, MySqlDataReader, MySqlCommand)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. When I leave it as
    Reader2.Read()

It just skips past the while loop

Comment: @user2960452: that's because the query is not reurning any value

Comment: If I run the query through navicat I get a result

Comment: As per @[Claudio-redi][1] my query was in fact invalid - I'll update in case anyone stumbles on this later the query didn't contain the % for the LIKE parameter

Many thanks for your help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/245860/claudio-redi

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
while (Reader2.Read()==false)
```

should be:

```
while (Reader2.Read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't disposed of the old `DataReader`. I suggest that you rigorously change everything to use `using` blocks. That gets rid of all of these problems. (Also enclose the connection in using-blocks. If an exception was thrown at the wrong moment, you'd leak a connection or a reader).